# How to make fire flow from one point of an object to another

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

I have a simple fire scene:[image]
As you can see, it's a ring with fire flowing up from it. How can I make the fire animation start with a small flame that grows, and eventually sets the entire ring on fire.

Comment: @cegaton If you edit one of my questions next time please don't misspell a word. Thanks!

Comment: Looks to me like  a typo, which you have simply edited and fixed. To avoid this happening in the future,  I would like to know if you are clear on why the edit, _ie_ removal of _"I don't care how you all want to do it, I just want it done."_, and other occurrences of _"I want"_  _"I want"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest way I could work out:
Use a 'screw' modifier on a circle, with an animated angle (and an empty to rotate the circle around), then use this as the emitter. You'd probably want to put it inside your torus object and make it not render.
This works in Blender 2.81a (old smoke sim) and Mantaflow (November 26th 2019 build).
here's what it looks like- https://youtu.be/7h7JBEYuu1Q

And here's the .blend file (old 2.81a smoke sim) to pull apart- https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfctf8g5x31j9iu/FireReveal01.blend?dl=0

I tried using a simple wipe white-over-black image sequence as a UV mapped texture on the emitter/flow object, but both the old smoke sim and Mantaflow ignored it (just got a quarter of the torus on fire that didn't move) so don't waste your time with that!